# Difference between MPI timer and CUDA timer

Tags: timer, cuda, mpi

I have a MPI program which will call a CUDA function. I measure the running time of the CUDA function with both MPI timer and CUDA timer. However, the measurement with MPI timer is 2 seconds greater than that with CUDA timer. I would like to know why this would happen.

The MPI program is structured as follows:

```
 int main(){
MPI initiation

Start timing with MPI_Wtime 

Call CUDA function

End timing with MPI_Wtime 

MPI finalization

}
```

The CUDA function is structured as follows:

```
void CUDA_fun(){

Start CUDA timer event 

Call global function

End CUDA timer event

}
```

Linux x86_64

GPU C2075

CUDA 4.2

MPICH2 1.4.1p1

Comment: 2 seconds is a lot of time. How long does the program take? 
Is it reasonable to think that this difference is due to data transfer/sync between the host and the GPU?

Comment: well can you share a working example code?

Comment: @igon The program takes 10 seconds. All the data transfer/sync is within CUDA function, and therefore is measured.

Comment: @pyCthon Let me try making a simplified version of the program tomorrow.

Comment: when you say CUDA timer, do you mean using cuda Events ?  Also, does the situation change if you put a `cudaFree(0);` before the `Start timing with MPI_Wtime` step?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Yes. I mean cuda Events. In the mpi program, I should not have any CUDA built-in function call like cudaFree(0) because it will cause compilation errors.

Comment: It's just for test purposes. Make another function in your CUDA module called `CUDA_start_fun()` if you prefer, that does nothing but the `cudaFree(0);` call.  Then call `CUDA_start_fun()` before the start timing with MPI step.  The purpose would be to separate out the GPU start up latency with the actual runtime of the operation in `CUDA_fun()`.

Comment: According to your example, you are timming a CUDA kernel call with CUDA events and a call to a function `CUDA_func` with MPI timers. The `CUDA_func` also has timing functions and may introduce an overhead. It seems you are not taking the same piece of code to compare the elapsed times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pQB states, the measurement difference between MPI timer and CUDA timer is caused by the overhead of launching CUDA events. I have carried out experiments with/without CUDA events. The results match the statement.

Update: As talonmies said, the extra time is the time required for CUDA context initialisation. In linux, by enabling persistence mode with nvidia-smi -pm 1, the extra time can be reduced.

Comment: I think you will find that CUDA events have almost no overhead. The extra time is the time required for CUDA context initialisation. This can take several seconds, depending on platform and the type and amount of code involved.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664627/linking-with-3rd-party-cuda-libraries-slows-down-cudamalloc#) for more information and examples of this effect

Comment: In addition to @talonmies's comment, I guess you are also including the memory allocation within the MPI timing

Comment: @talonmies When I commented out the CUDA timer, the program execution time measured by MPI timer has reduced by 2 seconds.

Comment: @pQB everything including memory allocation is within the MPI timing.

Comment: @talonmies OK. I know what really happen. I actually have two functions in my CUDA program. One calls CUDA routines, and therefore needs CUDA context initialization. The other one, the one I experimented with, does not involve any CUDA routines except the CUDA event. So when I comments out the CUDA event, there is no CUDA routine in it, and therefore no need to initialize CUDA context.